# How to build a dataframe instead of just printing list from a for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, loops

I have a for loop that generates a list but I'd like to turn that into a dataframe. I get stuck with how to correctly append the elements. Currently, this is my for loop and a snippet of what I get back

```
#find all course titles and print list
courseTitleElems = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//h3[@class='head']")
for courseTitleElem in courseTitleElems:
    courseTitle = courseTitleElem.text
    timeElems = courseTitleElem.find_elements_by_xpath("following-sibling::div/div[contains(@id,'children')]//div[contains(@class,'timeColumn')]")
    print("\n" + courseTitle)
    for timeElem in timeElems:
        timeColumn = timeElem.get_attribute("textContent").strip("\n")
        print("\n" + timeColumn)
```

and what prints is this

```
1- Freshman Computer Science
     F
     9am-9:50am
     M
     9am-9:50am
19- From Impossible to I'm Possible: Analysis of Impostor Phenomenon
     T
     10am-11:50am
     TH
     8am-9:50am
     W
     9am-9:50am
```

My goal is to build a dataframe that looks something like this

```
Course Title                      Day        Time
1- Freshman Computer Science      F          9am-9:50am
19- From Impossible to I'm..      M          9am-9:50am
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to put the values you want in a list of dictionaries or a list of lists. Then, you can give that list-of-dictionaries to `pandas.DataFrame()` and it'll create the dataframe for you. For example,

```
# This list will hold all the rows that we want to make the dataframe with
alldata = []

for courseTitleElem in courseTitleElems:
    courseTitle = courseTitleElem.text.strip()
    timeElems = courseTitleElem.find_elements_by_xpath("following-sibling::div/div[contains(@id,'children')]//div[contains(@class,'timeColumn')]")
    
    # Based on your output, it looks like items in timeElems alternate between day of week and time. 
    # So we take alternate elements as dayElem and timeElem using zip() and list slicing
    for dayElem, timeElem in zip(timeElems[::2], timeElems[1::2]):
        timeColumn = timeElem.get_attribute("textContent").strip() # strip ALL whitespace
        dayColumn = dayElem.get_attribute("textContent").strip()

        # Create the dictionary containing the data for each row
        courseinfo = {"Course Title": courseTitle, "Day": dayColumn, "Time": timeColumn}
        # Append the dictionary to the main list.
        alldata.append(courseInfo)

# Now that you've parsed everything, make the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(alldata)
```